# Как инкрементировать nullable-поле в kotlin

Tags: kotlin

В моей программе есть data-класс Person:

```
data class Person(var name: String) {
    var age: Int? = null
    var city: String? = null

    fun moveTo(newCity: String) {
        city = newCity
    }
    fun incrementAge() {
        age++
    }
}
```

Как инкрементировать nullable-поле age в функции incrementAge()?
С обычным не nullable-полем (заданным в конструкторе) всё бы отлично сработало, а как быть в данной ситуации?

Comment: а что значит инкрементировать null integer? что должно получиться после такой операции? Почему бы не задать дефолтное значение для данного поля, например 0 и не делать его null?

Comment: @IR42 Это значит, что недавно изучаю kotlin и только после вашего коммента понял, что так можно было сделать) Спасибо)

Comment: На случай что все-таки надо, можно так: `age = age?.inc()`

Comment: используйте age?.plus(1)